# Error on compling cachedb_cassandra module Opensips

Tags: makefile, cassandra, thrift, opensips

I am trying to compile cachedb_cassandra module to integrate my opensips with cassandra. However, on compiling , I am getting flow of

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/himanshu/opensips-1.10.0-tls/modules/cachedb_
Compiling cachedb_cassandra_dbase.cpp
Compiling cassandra_constants.cpp
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wold-style-definition" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
Compiling cassandra_types.cpp
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wold-style-definition" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
Compiling Cassandra.cpp 
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wold-style-definition" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ 
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wold-style-definition" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ 
In file included from cassandra_constants.h:9, 
                 from cassandra_constants.cpp:6: 
cassandra_types.h:9:20: error: Thrift.h: No such file or directory 
cassandra_types.h:10:35: error: TApplicationException.h: No such file or directory 
cassandra_types.h:11:32: error: protocol/TProtocol.h: No such file or directory 
cassandra_types.h:12:34: error: transport/TTransport.h: No such file or directory 
.
. 
.
```

There are many more errors after this, but I think that could be due to missing .h files error. 
`Opensips version is 1.10` . Thrift is installed. 
I tried making change in Makefile but got same result.  Is there anything I am missing.   Please help.

Thanks